# what's the timeline of the games in borderlands?

Tags: borderlands-series

So I was just wondering what the timeline for borderlands? Because I have borderlands 1,borderlands 2,borderlands the pre sequel,and tales from borderlands. So if you know please answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the chronological order of in-game events:

1. Borderlands
2. The Pre-Sequel!
3. Borderlands 2
4. Tales from the Borderlands
5. Borderlands 3

Comment: Note that this is the chronological order of in-game events. Suggested play  order is still release order, 1 - 2 - Pre-Sequel - Tales.